# Spring,Upload file into Server Root directory?

Tags: java, spring, file, file-upload

In my Spring Application, i have upload option,

When file upload to local directory, it is working fine and below working code.

```
 String orginalName = file.getOriginalFilename();
 String filePath = "C:SpringDemo/WebContent/WEB-INF/UploadedFiles/"+orginalName;
 File destination = new File(filePath);
 file.transferTo(destination);
```

But i want to Upload in my server root directory, in that i'm doing,

```
 String orginalName = file.getOriginalFilename();
 String filePath = "http://localhost:8080/SpringDemo/WebContent/WEB-INF/UploadedFiles/"+orginalName;
 File destination = new File(filePath);
 file.transferTo(destination);
```

This code was not working .. it is giving file directory not existing error.

so How to add file in my Server directory?

Comment: First of all, don't do it! Uploading it into the server directory is a bad idea. Store it somewhere else. Second, using `File` for this won't work, as it doesn't handle the `http` protocol.

Comment: but real time applications have done to save the file into sever directory, so in that time what they are doing?

Comment: It would be helpful if you add a more complete example. You can store the files anywhere on the file system (and even in a database), and then have a servlet retrieve it. Having them in the server directory opens up for many problems, like the webapplication has to be deployed as an exploded war, the files can be deleted on re-reployment etc.

Comment: Real applications have a option where a administrator can configure where to store the file. -- I you store the files in the server application folder, it will be deleted every time you deploy a new version of your application

Comment: Store file into Database or Store file into Directory!! Which one is good? which one is recommended?

Comment: That is another question, you should offer your usecase, so ppl. can help you to solve it.